# Access other widget instance through in .kv file

Tags: kivy, python-3.6, kivy-language

When I instantiate two classes (MainBoxLayout and Connection) like this in the app class:

```
class MartyApp(App, BoxLayout):

def build(self):
    self.title = 'Marty Robot App'
    self.orientation = 'vertical'
    self.add_widget(MainBoxLayout())
    self.add_widget(Connection())
    return self
```

How can I access the `Connection` class/instance in the `<MainBoxLayout>:` part of my kivy file? Here:

```
<MainBoxLayout>:
canvas:
    Color:
        rgb: [.121, .545, .912]
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size

<Connection>:
    available_martys: spinner_discovered_martys.values
    rows: 4
    cols: 1
    padding: 5
```

I've tried to create instantiate a `Connection` class in the `MartyApp` class, pass it as an argument to the `MainBoxLayout` class and return that instance, but then my app crashes straight and I don't know why.

Here an example:

```
class MartyApp(App, BoxLayout):
    conncetion = Conncetion()

def build(self):
    return MainBoxLayout(conncetion)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like `self.connection = Connection()` in your build method, then later get that object with `App.get_running_app().connection`, or equivalently `app.connection` in kv code.

Comment: Okay, so I create an object of that class in the `build` method of my `MartyApp` class. When I put a `<Connection>:` in the .kv file, will it take this object or create another one instead? Or more general: will `<Connection>:` or `Connection:` (as part of a widget) create another instance of that class?

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare an ObjectProperty to hook up to your Connection child widgets. Please refer to my example below for detail.

## main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty


class Connection(GridLayout):
    value = NumericProperty(0)


class MainBoxLayout(BoxLayout):

    avail_martys = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainBoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.access_connection()

    def access_connection(self):
        print(self.avail_martys.value)


class MartyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = "Marty Robot App"
        return MainBoxLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MartyApp().run()
```

## marty.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Connection>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 4
        cols: 1
        padding: 5

<MainBoxLayout>:
    avail_martys: conn

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [0.121, .545, 0.912]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

    Connection:
        id: conn
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Will I now access the property of the `<Connection>:` widget or the instantiated `Conncetion:` class within the `<MainBoxLayout>:` widget? Or are they the same, because they share the same class property and not a `self.value` property of the instance?

Comment: The class MainBoxlayout will then

Comment: <Connection> is a widget added in the kv rule file. Connection is a child widget in the <MainBoxLayout> widget rule. When the class MainBoxLayout is instantiated in the build method, it will do the work to instantiate the real attributes and other classes. You will be accessing the properties/variables of the instantiated Connection class.